# What are these recursively defined sequences called?

Tags: reference-request, sequences-and-series, computability-theory, terminology, binary-tree

Let $F(x,y)$ be a function of two variables, defined for all positive integers $x$ and $y$.  Define a sequence $a_n$ recursively by setting $a_1 = 1$ and
$$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} F(k, n-k) \cdot a_k a_{n-k}.$$

Is there a common name for such recursively defined sequences?  A study for some general classes of $F$?  I'll probably "show my cards" more in another post, but for now I'd like to search the literature a bit more... unfortunately I can't figure out the right term to search for!

Comment: Isn't this some type of convolution, perhaps?

Comment: I might call this a "weighted Catalan recurrence."

Comment: @SamHopkins Thanks!  That brings up a lot of interesting recurrences... nothing quite like what I want (yet?) but a good lead.

Answer (score 9):

The evaluation of your sequence is equivalent to the evaluation of certain weighted sums over binary trees. The resulting identities are often called *hook length formulas*.

Suppose $\mathcal B_n$ denotes the set of full binary trees with $n$ internal vertices. For some tree $T\in \mathcal B_n$ and vertex $v\in T$ we define the $F$-hook length of $v$ to be $H(v)=F(p+1,q+1)$ if the left tree below $v$ is in $\mathcal B_p$ and the right tree below $v$ is in $\mathcal B_{q}$. The elements of your sequence satisfy
$$a_{n}=\sum_{T\in \mathcal B_{n-1}}\prod_{v\in T}H(v).$$

A particularly cool example due to Postnikov is given by the hook function $F(p,q)=1+\frac{1}{p+q-1}$ which leads to the strikingly simple
$$a_n=n^{n-2}\frac{2^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}.$$
This sparked some curiosity about which functions $F$ give rise to simple evaluations for $a_n$. You can find more examples in the paper ["Hook Length Formulas for Trees by Han's Expansion"](https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.3342) by W. Chen, O. Gao, P. Guo but there are more papers out there on the topic.

All the investigated examples that I've seen use hook functions $F(p,q)$ that depend only on $p+q$. If we think in analogy with hook length formulas for partitions (where the analogue of Postnikov's formula is the Nekrasov-Okounkov formula) this is analogous to hook lengths being a sum $a+\ell+1$ where $a,\ell$ are the arm and leg of a box. The classical hook length formula, or Nekrasov-Okounkov formula use hook functions that depend only on $a+\ell$ but their $q,t$ generalizations, as well as the theory of Macdonald polynomials show that there are interesting formulas where the weight for each box depends on $a$ and $\ell$ separately. This makes me hopeful that the same can happen for trees, so I expect there to be hook length formulas for more general $F(p,q)$ that doesn't just depend on $p+q$.

Now, for those that are curious, such hook length formulas have been investigated for other classes of trees, and there is a unifying Hopf Algebraic perspective behind all such calculations. This is explained in ["Tree hook length formulae, Feynman rules and B-series"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6053) by B. Jones, K. Yeats.

Comment: Very nice answer!